# Does the commonly called "CPU frequency" reference the max or min value?

Tags: linux, cpu, clockspeed

Below is the output of cpuinfo, its max frequency is 1785 MHz and min 300 MHz. That is a huge gap between them, and it is confusing

What would be considered as the commonly referred to CPU frequency? Should the running time percent be considered since max frequency isn't used always?

```
Architecture:          aarch64
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,4,7
Off-line CPU(s) list:  1-3,5,6
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             3
CPU max MHz:           1785.6000
CPU min MHz:           300.0000
L1d cache:             unknown size
L1i cache:             unknown size
L2 cache:              unknown size
L3 cache:              unknown size
```

Comment: What kind of device is this? A laptop? Because to me this seems like a low-end laptop range. Like maybe a Chromebook or something? Because 300MHz is very low and 1,785MHz is high, but not high performance. My guess is that the 300MHz is the speed you get when not on battery power or the system goes into low power mode and is what you get when everything is normal and power is stable. I would not worry about this; whatever this device is it is clearly designed to work capably in that range.

Comment: PS: “Is what we talked about CPU frequency refer to the max or min value?” Doesn’t really make sense. The edit I made to make it “Is the commonly referred to CPU frequency refer to the max or min value?” is more in line with standard English. But if you wish to change it back, your choice.

Comment: How did you get that output.  It looks different to what I would expect.

Comment: It's an embeded system machine, I get this output by linux commnad “lscpu”

Answer (score 0):

In general the CPU will run at the top frequency required to service the load you are putting on the system (up to the max frequency).  This saves power.

The other times the CPU runs lower than the max frequency is when thermals dictate that it should throttle itself so as to not overheat.

The idea is you shouldn't need to think about it too much.  If you have a reason to run it at a particular clock frequency, you might be able to set that as a kernel boot parameter.  You can certainly do this on a Raspberry Pi running Linux, for example

Comment: FWIW, on my system lscpu shows the max MHz as being the Turbo frequency and my system generally sits not far off the min MHz value - although my minimum value is a lot higher then yours, being that its an old performance focussed CPU.    Depending on what I was doing, I would be concerned about the Off-line CPU's - that is not something I've ever noticed, and not present on my systems.

Answer (score 0):

The commonly referred to frequency is the maximum frequency the computer can run for sustained periods at.

To get it out the way - the Turbo speed is a speed that is higher then the maximum speed the CPU is designed to run at - the CPU will only run at this speed for short periods to give a boost in performance, but will go down to the rated speed in order to not overheat and damage the CPU.

The actual speed the CPU will run at will depend on the way Linux is programmed to work.  In general it will speed up as workload increases and slow down when under no or light load.   The minimum speed is the minimum speed the CPU will be at when not doing any work.  The reason for the speed variation is to save power.   (If you google Linux Speed Governor you should get a plethora of articles on how to tune the CPU for maximum speed, minimum power usage and almost anything in between)

Linux showing a CPU core running at 300MHz is not uncommon - especially on systems configured for maximum power saving -  and not an issue as long as the system is not heavily loaded - if it is running at that speed and the system is under load you can have a serious cooling issue.